# custom signup procedure using auth0 in angular

Tags: typescript, auth0, angularjs-1.5

I am trying to add more userinfo in same call. First signup with username, password in Auth0 and then on the callback continue to add userinfo to my database. But I can't get this to work. It hits the API even if the user is already existing in the Auth0-db.

Here is the code within the AuthService:

```
public signup(signupForm, callback) {
const self = AuthService._instance;
var result = "";


self._angularAuth0.signup({
  connection: "Users",
  responseType: "token",
  email: signupForm.email,
  password: signupForm.password
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);        
}, this.onSignupSuccess(signupForm));    
}

private onSignupSuccess(form) {
const self = AuthService._instance;

const newUser = {
  firstName: form.firstName,
  lastName: form.lastName,
  email: form.email,
  birthdate: new Date(form.birthYear, form.birthMonth, form.birthDay),
  auth0_UserId: this.userProfile.user_id,
  gender: form.gender
};

self._dataService.add(this.baseUrl + "/users/", newUser);
}
```

Inside app.ts:

```
angularAuth0Provider.init({
    clientID: "3LGkdfVvFfdsdfMpz1UVcwjh1jktrf7j",
    domain: "somedomain.eu.auth0.com",
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized",
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `this.onSignupSuccess` call inside callback. Currently it is passed as third parameter to `signup` method, that's why it is always executed.

```
self._angularAuth0.signup({
    connection: "Users",
    responseType: "token",
    email: signupForm.email,
    password: signupForm.password,
    auto_login: false
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    if(!error){
        this.onSignupSuccess(signupForm);
    }
});
```

After this you can login user manually. See examples [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js#login).

Comment: It doesn't work. It redirects to the callbackUrl before it hits the onSignupSuccess method.

Comment: Maybe is the callbackURL that is the problem ?

Comment: By default auth0 will auto login the user after successful signup. Try to specify `auto_login: false` option

Comment: Ok, that worked. But now I have to take care of the redirect my self ? How can I redirect to the page that the user was trying to visit ?

Comment: Problem now is I dont get any auth0_userId, because I dont get any access_token. So I dont know what to do. What I am trying to do is add the auth0_userId to my database on signup.